# Pokemon-like text display

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a Pokemon-style text display where when you click a key, the next line of text is displayed one by one. However my code doesn't seem to wait for me to press the key before exiting the sequence, and my entire exit function to the sequence does not run. Is there a way to make this happen?

Is there also a way to do this while accessing the text from a list?
EDIT: Apologies, I have recreated the code outside my program to show the problem. Sorry if the first code was a little messy :/

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
text_bg = pygame.Surface((640, 180))

game_messages = pygame.font.Font("fonts/Connection.otf", 30)

text1 = game_messages.render("Text number 1", False, (255,0,0))
text2 = game_messages.render("text number 2", False, (255,0,0))

text_list = [text1, text2]

running = 1
playing_text = 2
quits = 0
current_state = 1

def draw_text(text):
    screen.blit(text, (40, 360))

while current_state != quits:
    if current_state == running:
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
        pygame.display.flip()
        print("update")

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                current_state = playing_text
                screen.blit(text_bg, (0,300))

                for text in text_list:  # iterates over the list with all the messages
                        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                                quit()
                            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                                draw_text(text)
                                pygame.time.delay(50)

                                screen.blit(text_bg, (0, 300))
                                pygame.display.flip()

                                for t in range(len(text_list)):
                                    screen.blit(text_bg, (0, 300))
                                    draw_text(text)

                                    pygame.display.flip()

                                    pygame.event.clear(pygame.KEYDOWN)

                            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                                print("exit")
                                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                                    current_state = 1

                pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @mikeychee! Thanks for providing the code. I haven't worked with pygame in a while; how is `play_message` called? Also, after removing the spaces, it looks to me like the second `KEYDOWN` line is redundant. Could you rewrite the key detection?

Comment: @icedwater its called in the main loop in another file. Should i add that code here too?

Comment: @mikeychee could help if you had that in another block, but I'm not sure. See the advice above about a minimal reproducible example, as in: if I copy and paste all the code here, I should be able to reproduce the key part of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question, there's lots of complexity to this sort of thing - what about font size, word wrapping, legibility, etc. etc.?

I thought about it for a while, and I couldn't come up with a *nice* way of incorporating this into the main loop without all sorts of state-handling code all over the place.  So despite my opposition to multiple event loops, here is an example which implements what you suggest in a similar way.  The `playMessage()` function has its own event loop, handling enough to space-through the message, but also send important events (like Quit)  back to the main loop for processing.

Anyway, the key point in handling text in this manner is to count the number of key-presses, <kbd>space</kbd> in this case, and only show a new line on each press.  ( Also exit after the last line on press. )

Each line of text, when rendered into an image via `pygame.font.render()` will have its own height, which needs to be summed-up as the drawing proceeds down the screen.  So in effect the code has two "cursors": the position in the text-line-list, and the Y-pixel position on the display.

Since the code is blocking the main window event loop, it grabs a copy of the original screen-content and uses it to repaint the background.  This background is darkened and smoothed to make the text more legible (despite my choice of font).

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 700
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 300
WINDOW_SURFACE  = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE

DARK_BLUE = (   3,   5,  54 )
WHITE_ISH = ( 230, 230, 197 )

def playMessage( window, font, message, start_point=( 20, 20 ) ):
    line_separation = 3   # pixels between lines
    line_cursor     = 0

    # Make a blurred copy of the background for updating, by shrinking then
    # expanding the current content of the window, oh and darken it too
    # for better constrast
    skrinked   = pygame.transform.smoothscale( window, ( window.get_width()//4, window.get_height()//4 ) )
    dark       = pygame.Surface( ( skrinked.get_width(), skrinked.get_height() ), flags=pygame.SRCALPHA )
    dark.fill( ( 100, 100, 100, 0 ) )
    skrinked.blit( dark, (0,0), special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGBA_SUB )
    background = pygame.transform.smoothscale( skrinked, ( window.get_width(), window.get_height() ) )

    # cleanup messages, remove blank lines, et.al
    message_lines = []
    for line in message.split( '\n' ):
        line = line.strip()
        if ( len( line ) > 0 ):
            message_lines.append( line )

    # Make every text line into a bitmap 
    for i,line in enumerate( message_lines ):
        message_lines[i] = font.render( line, True, WHITE_ISH )

    # Start the render
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    done = False
    while not done:

        window.blit( background, ( 0,0 ) )
        x_pos, y_pos = start_point
        for i in range( 0, line_cursor ):
            text_rect = message_lines[i].get_rect()
            text_rect.x = x_pos
            text_rect.y = y_pos
            window.blit( message_lines[i], text_rect )
            # offset next line
            y_pos += text_rect.height + line_separation
        pygame.display.flip()

        # Handle user-input
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
                pygame.event.post( pygame.event.Event( pygame.QUIT ) )      # re-post this to handle in the main loop
                done = True
            elif ( event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN ):
                if ( event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE ):
                    done = True
                elif ( event.key == pygame.K_SPACE ):
                    line_cursor += 1
                    if ( line_cursor > len( message_lines ) ):
                        done = True   # space at end to dismiss

        clock.tick_busy_loop( 16 )   # don't need big FPS for read




### initialisation
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), WINDOW_SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("text player")

### Message Text For Displaying
poke_font = pygame.font.Font( 'Pokemon Solid.ttf', 24  )    # ref: https://fontmeme.com/fonts/pokmon-font/
message   = "You were eated all up by a Wild Wampus!\nAnd you never found the Key in the Dark Forest!\nRedo From Start."

### Background image
grassy_background = pygame.image.load( "grassy.jpg" )  # ref: http://www.plaintextures.com/
grassy_background = pygame.transform.smoothscale( grassy_background, ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )

### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
            # On mouse-click
            playMessage( window, poke_font, message )

    # Movement keys
    #keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
    #    print("up")

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    window.blit( grassy_background, ( 0, 0 ) )
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)


pygame.quit()
```

[image: demo animation]